# How can I open files with spaces in their names via wine app?

Tags: wine, launcher, .desktop

I have `.desktop` file for a wine-like app that opens MS Word:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Version=1.0
Icon=x-vmware-564d5302e9430a5d-1416be4d2596d246-Microsoft-Word-2010
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=false                                                                                                                                                       
NoDisplay=false                                                                                                                                                           
Name=Microsoft Word                                                                                                                                                       
StartupWMClass=Microsoft Word                                                                                                                                             
Exec=vmrun -T player -gu alx -gp 123 runProgramInGuest "/home/alx/vmware/office/windows-7.vmx" -activeWindow -interactive "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\WINWORD.EXE" Z:\lin%f
Comment=Run 'Microsoft Word 2010' in the virtual machine 'windows-7'
Name[en_US]=Word
```

It successfully opens docs, except the docs with names what contain spaces, it shows the error that cannot find such files, and in path it replaces spaces with `%%20`. Is it possible to somehow say: dono't convert spaces into `%20` in file names?

Comment: Are you sure it's not the `Z:\lin` prefix that's causing the target file to be not found? I'm not sure why you'd need that (I don't use wine), but if you *do*, the backslash probably needs to be escaped or protected with quotes.

Comment: lin - is shared folder inside Win VM, the path to host files from VM i starting from Z:\lin\  the rest path - is path of file that i am trying to open. so example of file path that opens fine: `Z:\lin\home\alx\docs\myword.docx`  example of file path that couldnt be opened: `Z:\lin\home\alx\docs\my word.docx`, so in Word app error shows incorrect file path: `Z:\lin\home\alx\docs\my%20word.docx`

Comment: ps. funny is that spaces is not a problem for Excel app, it opens files with spaces  in names, just with the same .desktop configuration, might be it related to WINWORD app itself?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I sorted it out.

To correctly open MS Word docs including files with spaces in their names, we need to do 2 things:

1. create a sh wrapper that will start WINWORD app with correct parameters:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

vmrun -T player -gu alx -gp 123 runProgramInGuest ./vmware/office/windows-7.vmx -activeWindow -interactive "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\WINWORD.EXE" "$(echo "$@" |sed -e 's;C:;Z:;' -e 's:/*/:\\\\:g')"
```

2. Modify the Exec line in the `.desktop` file to point to the wrapper above:

```
Exec=./bin/wordwrapper.sh Z:\\\lin%F
```

Where `lin` - shared folder inside windows VM for accessing host machine files, in case of Wine, there should be only `Z:%F`